# Métodos para adicionar um option ao meu select com os nomes das moedas de uma API

Tags: javascript, html, api

preciso saber um jeito de pegar apenas os nomes da moedas dentro de uma API e adicionar um option no meu elemento select, não sei como faço isso preciso de alguma ajuda.

Ai esta a API, ela me retorna os nomes e seus valores com base na conversão do Dólar

JS:

```
fetch('https://cdn.moeda.info/api/latest.json').then(r=>{
    return r.json()
}).then(corpo=>{ 
    
})
```

HTML:

```
 <select data-js="allmoedas" id=""></select>
  </select>
```

preciso saber um jeito de pegar apenas os nomes da moedas dentro de uma API e adicionar um option no meu elemento select, não sei como faço isso preciso de alguma ajuda.
Pensei em adiconar a API em um Array, mas dnv não consigo retornar apenas os nomes dela

Answer (score -4):

Para você pegar apenas os nomes das moedas, basta você usar a função `Object.keys(object)` no objeto "rates" que retorna da API. Os nomes das moedas estarão representadas por um array.

Comment: Muito obrigado <3